# How to show error text in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm setting the `EditText` error message using `setError`, for example:

```
editTextName.setError("Please enter your name");
editTextName.requestFocus();
```

The above works when the text views are in the activity itself, ie. an error icon and the text balloon are shown.

However, when text views are in a fragment, only the error icon is shown.

What is the correct procedure to show the error text balloon too?

Comment: *when text views are in a fragment, only the error icon is shown*, this should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourEdittext.setError("This field is required");
yourEdittext.requestFocus();
```

You should call request focus for this to get it work. Hope this helps.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/email_holder"
    android:id="@+id/password_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Try adding your layout like above.

Comment: I do have `requestFocus()` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It works when using TextInputLayout but it's based on the new material design. I'll mark it as answer because now the error message can be seen.