# TextInputLayout setError() doesn't appear inside fragment

Tags: java, android

The text I wrote for the setError() method of TextInputLayout doesn't appear inside a fragment. Tried various solutions but none of them worked...

```
<itdgroup.myhomedoc.SignUpTextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/email_input_layout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewAvenirBookFont">

<itdgroup.myhomedoc.CustomEditText
    android:id="@+id/input_email"
    android:layout_width="295dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_signup_edit_text"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/input_password"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>

</itdgroup.myhomedoc.SignUpTextInputLayout>
```

```
                String strUserName = eMail.getText().toString();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strUserName) || !isEmailValid(strUserName)) {
                    emailTIL.setError("Please enter valid email");
                    return;
```

This is the custom TextInputLayout

````
public class SignUpTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
    private Context context;

    public SignUpTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public SignUpTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public SignUpTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();

        EditText editText = getEditText();
        if(editText != null) {
            editText.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.context, R.drawable.custom_signup_edit_text));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setError(@Nullable final CharSequence error) {
        super.setError(error);

        EditText editText = getEditText();
        if(editText != null) {
            editText.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.context, R.drawable.error_signup_edit_text));
        }
    }
```
````

Comment: share your code first

Comment: And what is SignUpTextInputLayout?

Comment: I added the code. It is a custom textIputLayout I created

Comment: how you initialized `emailTIL` ?

Comment: emailTIL = v.findViewById(R.id.email_input_layout1);

Comment: maybe show us SignUpTextInputLayout class?

Comment: The thing is that the code is working inside an activity but not inside a fragment

Comment: If you remove the setError method does it work?

Comment: The errorTextAppearance style

    <style name="error_appearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#bf1705</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>

Comment: it's running well the background changed just the text doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

In your overridden method of setError try adding the setError method as well :

```
@Override
public void setError(@Nullable final CharSequence error) {
    super.setError(error);

    EditText editText = getEditText();
    if(editText != null) {
        editText.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.context, R.drawable.error_signup_edit_text));
        editText.setError("Please enter valid email");
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than setting the setError method to the TextInpuLayout, have you tried setting it directly to the EditText ?

Comment: This is working but not as I designed the background and the under text

Comment: The thing is that my code is working well inside an activity but not inside the fragment

Comment: can you send a screenshot or image of how you want it to be?

Comment: I have found something which might help you, try this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229634/set-error-textinputlayout-in-fragment

Comment: Another link which might help :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220781/how-to-show-error-text-in-a-fragment/34220922#34220922

Comment: I tried all of the above and the other solutions I found before writing the question...

Comment: can you send a screenshot or image of what you exactly want?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiluM7flP3kAhUNyaQKHdtkAWoQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F36912602%2Ftextinputlayout-not-showing-error-message-after-clearing&psig=AOvVaw2W1oLJ_COwv_bKPOrytsvO&ust=1570091489873050

Comment: just showing the text under the edit text as appears in the link above

Comment: I have tried the code you have given, it is working for both  Fragment and Activity. Now you need to provide me with the Custom Edit Text class and the custom_signup_edit_text drawable you are using.

Comment: requestFocus()  doesnt work in TextLayoutInput, I tried it already

Comment: @OferWormser Your code is working for me in both Fragment and Activity, please provide me with your EditText custom class and drawable of custom_signup_edit_text and your custom style which you have used.